# Google Sheets: Conditional Formatting in Cell based on TEXT in another Cell, Not Number Value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

How do I create a conditional formatting rule in Google Sheets that changes the **colour** of a cell based on the **text** in another cell?

I want to create a rule whereby if I type "tested" in ANY cell, the two following cells in the row change colour automatically to show the testing window.

The sheet is very large so I need to also know how to make this rule apply to all cells, without all formatting relating to the text in just one cell - it always needs to be the cell with the text relating to the following two cells in the row.

Thanks in advance!

I've tried to use the basic conditional formatting, and tried googling, but all answers are based on a number value and don't apply when I try to use the same custom formula.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=A1="tested"
```

and 2 rules. one for `B1:Z` and 2nd for `C1:Z`

[image]